# How to create Multi-select picklist in .design class for configuring lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, multi-select, design-attributes

*Note: I'm trying to implement "Multi-Select Picklist" in design source for configuring lightning component, Not a Picklist in design source for configuring lightning component.
For reference I followed this: https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_lightning_datasource_picklists.htm

I'm able to create Multi-select picklist with .design class in lightning component with design:attribute, see below screenshots for reference. But when I'm passing datasource for that Multi-select picklist then I'm getting below error.

Error I got is: Failed to save MyComponent.design: Only String attributes may have a datasource in the design file.: Source

here it is multi-select picklist in design source

[image]

when I click on that select button, I'm getting Multi-select popup as well like below,

[image]

But when I'm pass datasource then I'm getting that below error.

My code is:
MyComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="MyVelues" type="String[]" />
</aura:component>
```

MyComponent.design

```
<design:component label="MyComponent">

     <design:attribute name="MyVelues" datasource="value1,value2,value3" default="value1" />
</design:component>
```

the error message is here

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, only String, Boolean, and Integer types are supported for use with design attributes at the moment. I don't believe what you are trying to achieve is possible at this time.

Comment: For reference I followed this: https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_lightning_datasource_picklists.htm

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate as you're asking about multi select picklist. This link is interesting as I was not aware about this. I would assume it's a doc issue and that this features isn't available, but to be sure I asked for more information here: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009NfE&fId=0D53A00003SQc1j

Comment: Yes @FabienTaillon, Its not a duplicate. My question is different from the above mentioned duplicate question. Here I'm trying to implement Multi-select picklist, not a normal/regular single select picklist.